# Isolate substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following string:

```
24^5915^7569^10070-3
```

How do I isolate the "10070" from it? In theory, I'd get the last item from the caret-delimited list, then split that. Can do it in ColdFusion but not jQuery. I need to note that the list/array can vary in length, i.e. there could be more or fewer caret delimiters, but the "-" delimiter will only ever be one, at the very end.

Comment: Did you try string.substring()? Try here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: If there are more `-` delimiters, what is the expected output? Could you put an input-output example for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner:

```js
console.log("24^5915^7569^10070-3".split("^").pop().split("-").shift());
```

If you can figure out a proper regular expression that suits your needs, you can also solve it (probably in a more elegant way) using [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Answer (score 1):

You could user pattern matching with a regex:

```js
console.log("24^5915^7569^10070-3".match("[\^][0-9]+[-]")[0].slice(1, -1));
```

It takes the pattern `^numbers-` the removes `^` and `-` from the first match.